# program headers and section headers in ELF files

Tags: c, linker, loader, elf

This is a repeat of a question but I could not quickly find an answer to my question. That's why asking it.

Some ELF files contain(executables or shared libs) program headers which explain segments.
They contain a field called virtual address and file offsets and some other fields.

There are also corresponding sections which explain "address in memory" and file offset.

Now I am little confused how sections and segments are related. (For statically compiled executables and for non-statically compiled executables.) 
How file offsets are different for statically compiled binaries? Is there any relation between virtual address in program headers and memory address in section headers.

Thanks

Comment: I myself found a nice article which clears most of my confusion: "http://mylinuxbook.com/readelf-command/"

Comment: Could you summarize what you've learned in the form of answer to your question?

Answer (score 3):

A *section* is the smallest continuous region of the file. So ELF files are subdivided into sections. Sections cannot overlap, that is, no byte can possibly be part of more than one section. But there can be bytes that don't belong to any section ("garbage").

Sections are generally used for linking purposes. They contain different parts of the file that can be rearranged, merged etc. by the linker.

But executable files can contain sections too – to describe the contents of the file, and where each piece of code or data begins. Shared objects use sections too. Those contain symbol tables for dynamic linking & stuff like that.

All sections contained in the ELF file are described in the Section Headers Table, each section having an entry in it.

But in order to make an executable, you need something else: *segments*. These tell the loader which parts of the file it should load into memory and to what addresses. So segments map into the executable process's memory space. They can contain code as well as data, so **segments can be subdivided into sections** to achieve that. And I guess that's the answer to your question.

Loadable segments are described in the Program Headers Table.

Long story short:
In executables, you have segments, that can be subdivided further into sections. Segments are loaded into the process's memory. Sections are optional, but can help subdivide the segments further or describe their contents.
In relocatable modules (compiler outputs, .o files) it's the other way around: *sections* are required, because they describe what's in the file and allow for linking.

---

As for the memory addresses & stuff:
On modern systems only the virtual addresses matter. A process is being deceived by the operating system that it runs alone in memory, with the entire address space available to it (though not *all* the address space could be available at the same time due to physical memory limitations). The system maps virtual addresses to physical addresses on the fly, transparently to the process.

Physical addresses are not used, so they can be left as zeros, but could be set to the same addresses just in case.